# Is it possible to build HTML template dynamically with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have got a project where I have to build the table template dynamically based on the values from the SQL server stored procedure.

I have got the following records

```
QuestD  QuestionType ResponseCount    Question  

2806     E             1              Organization Name: 
2807     E             1              Contact Name: 
2808     E             4              Rider Name:

2815     C             1              Date Requested (Radio Button): 
2816     C             4              Event Selected (Checkbox):
```

Here QuestionType = E means build <input tag
ResponseCount = 1 means only one input tag next to the question.

but ReponseCount = 4 means I need 4 input tag needed next to the question.

For QustionType = C means = It could be either Radio or Checkboxes.
but for Radio or Checkbox, the value would come from the database.

Please guide me how to proceed to solve this dynamic problem. I have never
dealt with generating dynamic HTML content with angularJS.

Is it possible to build the table with angularJS?

---

```
 [
  { 
    "QuestinID": 2806,
    "QuestionType": "E",
    "ResponseCount": 1,
    "Question": "Organization Name:"
  },

  {
    "QuestinID": 2807,
    "QuestionType": "E",
    "ResponseCount": 1,
    "Question": "Contact Name: "
  },

  {
    "QuestinID": 2804,
    "QuestionType": "E",
    "ResponseCount": 4,
    "Question": "Rider Name:"
  },

  {
    "QuestinID": 2805,
    "QuestionType": "C",
    "ResponseCount": 1,
    "Question": "Mobility or Other Challenges?"
  },

  {
    "QuestinID": 2815,
    "QuestionType": "C",
    "ResponseCount": 1,
    "Question": "Date Requested:"
  },

  {
    "QuestinID": 2816,
    "QuestionType": "C",
    "ResponseCount": 4,
    "Question": "Event Selected:"
  }
]
```

For Date Selected:

```
[ '01-JAN-2019', '02-JAN-2019', '03-JAN-2019', '03-JAN-2019' ]
```

For Event Selected:

```
[ 'Event1','Event2','Event3','Event4']
```

[image]

---

I would like to see

```
<label>Rider 1:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider1" /> <br /> 
<label>Rider 2:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider2" /> <br /> 
<label>Rider 3:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider3" /> <br /> 
<label>Rider 4:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider4" />
```

Comment: can you provide sample json please

Comment: Read [AngularJS Tutorial - Step 2 - AngularJS Templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). It explains how to generate HTML dynamically from a model.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be appropriate for new users as georgeawg stated in comments:

> One should avoid using function calls in AngularJS expressions as
> those functions are called multiple times every digest cycle

Something like this should do the trick for you

html

```
<table ng-repeat="item in data">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      {{item.Question}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="item.QuestionType == 'E'">
    <td ng-repeat="response in getArray(item.ResponseCount) track by $index">
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="item.QuestionType == 'C'">
    <td ng-repeat="response in getArray(item.ResponseCount) track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
  $scope.getArray = function(num) {
      return new Array(num);   
  }
```

Few important things to remember

1. You can use ng-repeat to crease as much input tags as needed
2. You can use ng-if directive to display different html for different cases

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlRlwcLufhmGj4gk63fh?p=preview)**

Improved answer according to the georgeawgs suggestions in comment.

js

```
  //prepare data in controll
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
      var responseArray = [];
      
      for(i = 0; i< value.ResponseCount; i++){
          var responseData = {};
          responseArray.push(responseData);
      }
      
      value.ResponseArray = responseArray;    
  });
```

html

```
<table ng-repeat="item in data">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        {{item.Question}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="item.QuestionType == 'E'">
      <td ng-repeat="response in item.ResponseArray track by $index">
        <input ng-model="response.data" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="item.QuestionType == 'C'">
      <td ng-repeat="response in item.ResponseArray track by $index">
        <input ng-model="response.data" type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[New Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUTa3LOdIdvYpY0lJGQd?p=preview)**

Comment: Could you please share the reason for downvote? It would help me to improve answer.

Comment: When creating examples, one should avoid patterns that will cause novice users problems. One should avoid using function calls in AngularJS expressions as those functions are called multiple times every digest cycle.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks alot for the feedback, I appreciate it. Any suggestions for a better solution or may I ask how would you tackle this problem.

Comment: @NTP. Thanks for your input and is really good starting point. How do you add ng-model as you build the loop? At the end I have to submit the responses to the database.

Comment: Initialize the response arrays in the controller and add the approprate `ng-model` directives to the inputs.

Comment: @georgeawg, I would like to see

<label>Rider 1:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider1" />
<br />
<label>Rider 2:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider2" />
<br />
<label>Rider 3:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider3" />
<br />
<label>Rider 4:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.rider4" />

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you for improvements. I should also get the habit of doing this, this way.

Comment: Thank you @NTP and georgeawg very much for your input. I have modified the code a little bit to display in a table format. Currently, I am working to build the model dynamically. With hard-coded model, it is displaying according to my output. Once I am done building the model, I will put the jason format about the model.

Comment: @NTP I did not down-vote your answer at all. You help me a lot to start solving my issues. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alomoni you can also put your label inside the inner ng-repeat

Comment: @NTP thanks your input. Could you please show me in another demo how to display the label if you do not mind?